# EF composite primary key violation on AddOrUpdate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, composite-primary-key

I am trying to create 2 tables. One for shops and one for cash registers. Cash registers have composite key: Id + ShopId

Here is a model:

```
public class Shop
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ShopName { get; set; }
}

public class CashRegister
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CashRegisterName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ShopId")]
    public Shop Shop { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how migration looks like:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.CashRegisters",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ShopId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    CashRegisterName = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Id, t.ShopId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Shops", t => t.ShopId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.ShopId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Shops",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ShopName = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

And here is the code that throws primary key violation exception:

```
        var context = new Model();

        var shops = new List<Shop>
        {
          new Shop() { ShopName = "First shop" },
          new Shop() { ShopName = "Second shop" }
        };

        context.Shops.AddOrUpdate(shops.ToArray());
        context.SaveChanges();

        var cashRegisters = new List<CashRegister>();

        foreach (var shop in shops)
        {
            cashRegisters.Add(new CashRegister()
            {
                CashRegisterName = "First cash register",
                ShopId = shop.Id
            });

            cashRegisters.Add(new CashRegister()
            {
                CashRegisterName = "Second cash register",
                ShopId = shop.Id
            });
        }

        context.CashRegisters.AddOrUpdate(a => new { a.Id, a.ShopId }, cashRegisters.ToArray());
        context.SaveChanges();
        //primary key violation exception on line above
```

Now obviously cash registers have 0 as an Id upon creation.
The exception I get is:

`"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.CashRegisters'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CashRegisters'. The duplicate key value is (0, 1).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."`

I tried adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to `CashRegister.Id`
but then I get another exception `{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'TestCompositeKeys.dbo.CashRegisters'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`, which is strange, since `Id` is not even nullable.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong or how do I fix this? Thank you

Comment: Perhaps in your `CashRegister` you need to assign the `Shop` property (the object), not only the foreign key.

Comment: @JoseLuis thank you for comment, however it didn't help. I added an exception message I am getting. I believe a first record is inserted with Id (0, 1), then the second one is inserted with Id (0,1) which leads to exception. If it wasn't a composite key it would have worked fine

Comment: I would like to understand *why* you use a composite primary key. Normally, in the rare cases where it is needed, every part of the key will be determined by other existing entities, so a compound key would never have an auto-generated component.

Comment: @grek40 the reason I am considering using composite keys is because records are generated on several machines and then are pulled in a single db. For example a sale would have integer Id,  CashId and ShopId. If there would be a single integer id then there will be collisions.  I could have used Guids but i would like not to

Comment: Thats not a reason at all.

Comment: @grek40 I updated previous comment

Comment: Unless you have a distributed database I don't see how duplicate Ids could happen when you insert items from multiple machines as long as the Id is auto-generated on database side. Even with distributed database the solution would be GUID Ids and not composite keys.

Comment: @grek40 Thats thr case.  I would have sql server compact on each machine with the table structure identical to central mssql db table structure

Comment: @grek40 I would like to avoid using Guids, thats why I am experimenting with composite key

Comment: Can you show the Migration code with the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute? It should somehow work, though your `CashRegisters.AddOrUpdate` is still wrong.

Comment: @grek40 sure. I am at lunch atm. Will post it in half an hour

Comment: @grek40 I've tried setting `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` on `CashRegister.Id` and it worked! Not sure why it didn't work out before.

Comment: @grek40 Would you like to post this suggestion as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `CashRegister.Id` to auto-increment should actually work.

```
public class CashRegister
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
```

The other thing to consider is the `AddOrUpdate` statement. Since `Id` will only be assigned when it is actually inserted, you can't really compare entries by Id. Instead you could try the following:

```
context.CashRegisters.AddOrUpdate(a => new { a.ShopId, a.CashRegisterName  }, cashRegisters.ToArray());
```

It will only use initialized properties for comparison and will really prevent re-insertion, while with `a.Id, a.ShopId` you would probably get duplicates when executing the seed second time.

Answer (score 1):

This Code here

```
foreach (var shop in shops)
        {
            cashRegisters.Add(new CashRegister()
            {
                CashRegisterName = "First cash register",
                ShopId = shop.Id
            });

            cashRegisters.Add(new CashRegister()
            {
                CashRegisterName = "Second cash register",
                ShopId = shop.Id
            });
        }
```

will insert 4 CashRegister object. two each for both shops. When ShopId is set as a primary key, then for CashRegister Table can not have same ShopId twice.

The solution is either insert one CashRegister object for each Shop object or remove primary constraint from ShopId.